# Multiple sources to hive database

Tags: streamsets

I am getting multiple sources like the below and how to process to hive table using streamsets piepline

Ex:

- 1st day - 10 flat files(.csv format)
- 2nd day - 10 flat files and 10 pdf files
- 3rd day - 10 oracle tables and 10 flat files

using streamsets need to process the data into hive with dynamic sources

Comment: You might do better to ask in the StreamSets community - there are multiple options, including a dedicated Q&A site: https://streamsets.com/community

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate pipeline for each source. Also, there is no off-the-shelf origin for PDF files. You would need to look at using a scripting origin or custom Java origin to do that.